# Can't Unchecked chekbox with reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I use a checkbox on a website and I don't know why but I can't unchecked this checkbox.

```
    const [checkBoxEmailPersonalized, setCheckBoxEmailPersonalized] = useState(false);

    const onEmailPersonalized = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        setCheckBoxEmailPersonalized(event);
    }
    
    return (
       <div className="wrapper wrapper-with-nav pt-5">
         <div className="container">
           <div class="row">
             <div className="form-group col-md-2 checkbox-custom">
              <input type="checkbox"
               id="checkBoxEmailPersonalized" 
               name="checkBoxEmailPersonalized" 
               checked={checkBoxEmailPersonalized}
               className="form-control"
               onChange={event => onEmailPersonalized(event.target.value)}/>
              <label htmlFor="checkBoxEmailPersonalized" className="form-label multiline">{t('EMAIL')}</label>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    )
```

In my console log I have all time the value `ON`

Do you know why I can't unchecked this checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `e.target.value` to `e.target.checked`